# Missing some libraries because of gradle.properties file in Android project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, travis-ci, gradlew

My project contains two flavours A and B.
I build the app using this command: 
`./gradlew clean assembleDebug`

Therefore, I get two .apk files in `~/MY_PROJECT/builds/output/apk` folder each size 7.5M.

Recently, I [have read](https://medium.com/@erikhellman/boosting-the-performance-for-gradle-in-your-android-projects-6d5f9e4580b6) that I can decrease build time by using `gradle.properties` file and having following lines of code in it:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

According to above doc, this file should be inside `~/MY_PROJECT/.gradle/gradle.properties` of project's home directory. Since this folder is not under version control I put it under the root of project. There was no complain and I could build two flavours based on above command. However, I surprised with the result. FlavourA has 5.5M while FlavourB has 7.5M. I installed FlavourA on a device and not surprisingly crashed on launch time due to a missing library.

By deleting `gradle.properties` file then everything goes fine. So, What you think should I ask every developers to create `gradle.properties` file and add those two lines inside it? Even I'm able to do this What should I do with Travis?

Comment: `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` is not the project's home directory. You can put the `gradle.properties` file inside the root for your project or inside the `~/home/user/.gradle/` folder (general)

Comment: Thanks. My main problem is to notify Travis in order to reduce build time. So I was looking a way to do that maybe by Env or similar... I have no idea is it possible :(